# macgap scrolling issue when position fixed

Tags: css, macos

I just installed [MacGap2](https://github.com/MacGapProject/MacGap2) to create a mac version of my webapp using a simple iframe but it seems that the CSS property `'position:fixed'` creates issues when scrolling, it jumps up and down a little making it completely un-usable. Does anybody know how to fix this?

As you can see in the below screen shot, my headerbar and left menu end up in the middle of the screen when I scroll but then jitters back up when I finish scrolling.

Here's a little tiny video to illustrate: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtyC-3Uqqt8&feature=youtu.be

[image]

Here is the CSS code for the left menu

[image]

Comment: Can you post the css code you are using to position that element as fixed?
That may be some bug between macgap and css positioning :/

Comment: @AntónioRegadas Added in main post :) Thanks!

Comment: I tried to remove the transition effect but it didn't fix it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trying and playing around. And looking at other Macgap apps. It seems the only solution is to get rid of the global scroll bar and create a sub-div with it's own scroll bar.

So you make sure that there is no overflow on your site, and where ever you have content, make that div have a scroll bar and it works!

Answer (score 2):

Add:

```
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
```

...and see what happens!

edit (as per mod's request): webkit browsers have a bug for fixed elements that behave in the manner the op describes. Using the above code on the fixed element will most probably fix the jumpiness.

Comment: I would appreciate if the answer has some info, bcoz code only answers are not appreciated

Comment: Thanks. Tried it, but no cookie yet... I also saw this post https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=425016

Comment: Added a tiny video to show the issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PtyC-3Uqqt8&feature=youtu.be The "Need help" Shouldn't be moving at all...

Comment: ...wrap the whole element inside of the code I sent you. Also avoid any relative elements inside of that. And one more thing I learned from experience. Try adding all the fixed element's content inside an absolutely positioned element. If you had the site somewhere online I could have helped more

Comment: I didn't try wrapping the whole thing yet, just tried it first on each elements (I have 3 elements with position:fixed) and inside of those I can't do any other position:fixed :S Going to have to find a workaround for those.

Comment: Can I just put your -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); on the body?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend it - applying this to the body would mean putting all the content to the mobile's graphics memory, which in turn, depending on content and the device's gfx ram could either work or crash the browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried it again and it seems the only fix was to make a div with my content scrollable instead of the whole window and now it works.